# the cropped image sends an empty array

Tags: python

I am trying to use Yolov3 to make prediction on a class person only.
I want to crop the image, but I get an empty array of the cropped image.
Thank you in advance

here is my code

```
from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3
img_raw = image.load_img("C:/Users/mamal/Downloads/person.jpg", target_size=(416, 416))
from absl import app, logging, flags

flags.DEFINE_string('classes', '../projet_yoga/yolov3-tf2/data/coco.names', 'path to classes file')
flags.DEFINE_string('weights', '../projet_yoga/yolov3-tf2/checkpoints',
                    'path to weights file')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('tiny', False, 'yolov3 or yolov3-tiny')
flags.DEFINE_integer('size', 150, 'resize images to')
flags.DEFINE_string('image', '../projet_yoga/yolov3-tf2/data/girl.png', 'path to input image')
flags.DEFINE_string('tfrecord', None, 'tfrecord instead of image')
flags.DEFINE_string('output', '../projet_yoga/yolov3-tf2/output.jpg', 'path to output image')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_classes', 80, 'number of classes in the model')

app._run_init(['yolov3'], app.parse_flags_with_usage)

import tensorflow as tf

yolo = YoloV3(classes = 80)
yolo.load_weights("C:/Users/mamal/Desktop/projet_yoga/yolov3-tf2/checkpoints/yolov3.tf").expect_partial()

boxes, scores, classes, nums = yolo(tf.expand_dims(np.asarray(img_raw), 0))

person_boxes = boxes[classes == 0][0]

img_raw = np.asarray(img_raw)

left, top, right, bottom = (left*img_raw.shape[1]), (top*img_raw.shape[0]), (right*img_raw.shape[1]), (bottom*img_raw.shape[0])

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_raw = cv2.imread("C:/Users/mamal/Downloads/person.jpg")
crop_img = img_raw[top:bottom, left:right]
crop_img
>>>>array([], shape=(0, 640, 3), dtype=uint8)

left, top, right, bottom = person_boxes
```

Comment: why did you load your `img_raw` twice?

Comment: no particular reason I thought it could change something in the 'crop_img' but it didn't

Comment: try printing your left, top, right and bottom variable. I tried the same thing using numbers only and it works.

Comment: I get this :      `(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=-1.1592909>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.003174572>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.1592909>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0031745743>)`

Comment: Are you trying to detect, then crop, or crop, then detect? You seem to run this code on jupyter notebook / google colab right? Are you sure the code is in order?

Comment: I want to detect  the classe ( person) and crop the detected class based on the coordinate of the boxe.  yes I run it on jupyter notebook

Comment: can you also print the `person_boxes` please

Comment: I get this `<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([-1.1592909 ,  0.00317457,  1.1592909 ,  0.00317457], dtype=float32)>`

Comment: Your cropping won't work because you need a float coordinate for your cropping point. But instead, what you got is a tensor object. That's why it can't crop.